# What are the alternatives to store a external XML file without the XSLT document function in XSLT2.0?

Tags: xslt-2.0

What are the alternatives to store a external XML file without the XSLT document function in XSLT2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document` functions exists since XSLT 1.0, but not to store a secondary XML document, but rather to load it.

With XPath and XSLT 2.0 for a single document you can also use the `doc` function to load the document e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="doc('foo.xml')//bar"/>`. And there is the `collection` function which often allows accessing a collection of files (e.g. those in a directory) but the exact syntax depends on the XSLT processor/XSLT implementation.

Comment: Thanks @martin but could you please provide a example to show how the collection function works .

Comment: How collection works depends on the XSLT 2.0 processor or the XQuery 1.0 implementation. With Saxon 9 you can process files in a directory using e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="collection('file:///C:/dir/subdir?select=*.xml')"/>`, see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/html/sourcedocs/collections.html for details.